# Event validation issue with updatepanel "Invalid postback or callback argument"

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, eventvalidation

I am an UpdatePanel virgin and I'm having problems.

I have 2 drop down lists. I am basically trying to update the contents of the second drop down depending on what I select on the first drop down. In chrome this all works fine. In IE it doesn't seem to do anything the first time I change the drop down box selection and once I do it a second time it gives the error below.

I have read that I need to register the control for validation. So i tried the following.

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(DropDown1.UniqueID, "1");
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(Dropdown2.UniqueID, "2");

            base.Render(writer);
        }
```

My two drop down boxes are within a user control so the Render code I have placed at the user control level but it doesn't seem to help. Is there some key thing I'm missing here?

**Server Error in '/' Application.**

> Invalid postback or callback argument.
>   Event validation is enabled using
>   
>   in configuration or <%@ Page
>   EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a
>   page.  For security purposes, this
>   feature verifies that arguments to
>   postback or callback events originate
>   from the server control that
>   originally rendered them.  If the data
>   is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation
>   method in order to register the
>   postback or callback data for
>   validation.  Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:**

> System.ArgumentException: Invalid
>   postback or callback argument.  Event
>   validation is enabled using  in
>   configuration or <%@ Page
>   EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a
>   page.  For security purposes, this
>   feature verifies that arguments to
>   postback or callback events originate
>   from the server control that
>   originally rendered them.  If the data
>   is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation
>   method in order to register the
>   postback or callback data for
>   validation.

**Source Error:**

> An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current
>   web request. Information regarding the
>   origin and location of the exception
>   can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.

**Stack Trace:**

> [ArgumentException: Invalid postback
>   or callback argument.  Event
>   validation is enabled using  in
>   configuration or <%@ Page
>   EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a
>   page.  For security purposes, this
>   feature verifies that arguments to
>   postback or callback events originate
>   from the server control that
>   originally rendered them.  If the data
>   is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation
>   method in order to register the
>   postback or callback data for
>   validation.]
>   System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.ValidateEvent(String
>   uniqueId, String argument) +8656758
>   System.Web.UI.Control.ValidateEvent(String
>   uniqueID, String eventArgument) +113
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList.LoadPostData(String
>   postDataKey, NameValueCollection
>   postCollection) +55
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList.System.Web.UI.IPostBackDataHandler.LoadPostData(String
>   postDataKey, NameValueCollection
>   postCollection) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData(NameValueCollection
>   postData, Boolean fBeforeLoad) +327
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +878

Comment: This is not an answer but in practice, I've almost always ended up just disabling it with `EnableEventValidation="false"`. Once you get into any kind of basic client/server interaction outside the core .NET controls it's impossible to make anything work with it enabled. This doesn't really offer you any substantive security anyway, your page should always ensure that posted data is parsed and handled properly.

Comment: But the UpdatePanel is one of there controls so disabling there event security sounds like a bad idea. Surely it is designed to work with the Ajax Toolkit?